# Ctypes Python. Как использовать арифметические операции?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Для примера привожу код:

```
from ctypes import c_longlong as ll
k = ll(10**17-1)
k-=1
```

Данный код не работает

```
from ctypes import c_longlong as ll
k = ll(10**17-1)
k-=ll(1)
```

И так тоже.
Как реализовать арифметику в "сишных" типах?
Как предоставить классу метод **add** ? Или есть другие способы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких ситуациях надо использовать операцию `dir`:

```
>>> dir(k)
['__bool__', '__class__', '__ctype_be__', '__ctype_le__', '__ctypes_from_outparam__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_b_base_', '_b_needsfree_', '_objects', '_type_',
'value']
```

И очевидно что value это то поле которое нужно

```
>>> k.value
99999999999999999
>>> k.value -= 1
>>> k
c_longlong(99999999999999998)
```

Другой способ - это `help(k)`. Ну и конечно можно просто прочитать документацию к ctypes.